# How do I make a dataframe table to show in html

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a dataframe like this which I created using the function below in app.py

```
                 cases    deaths
state                             
New York      1203003648  31391997
California    2188008059  30864267
Texas         1745177048  28252336
Florida       1461739406  22255383
New Jersey     561292201  15263394
Pennsylvania   672001545  14669903
```

app.py

```
def find_top_confirmed_states(n = 10):

    df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv')
    by_state = df.groupby('state').sum()[['cases', 'deaths']]
    tcs = by_state.nlargest(n, 'deaths')
    return tcs

tcs = find_top_confirmed_states()

@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html", table=tcs, cmap=html_map, list=tcs.values.tolist())
```

index.html

```
                {% for p in list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ p[0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ p[1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ p[2]}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

Now I just want to show this table in html

My table is not showing. The best that I could do was to show the number of cases and death, but I can't make the states to show. How do I work with this dataframe that will show in a table in html

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has a built-in `DataFrame.to_html()`. You can take that text directly and embed it in your website.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: thank you but I wan to iterate through my table. So I would rather just make my dataframe in like an array or something like that where I can use a for loop to iterate. Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```py
def Index():
    return df.to_html(header="true", table_id="table")
```

or

```py
def Index():
    return render_template('file.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data')], titles=df.columns.values
```

and `html` jinja template for above method:

```py
{% for table in tables %}
  {{titles[loop.index]}}
  {{ table|safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

also is possible to use `render_template` and remove `{{titles[loop.index]}}` line

```
return render_template('file.html',  tables=[df.to_html(classes='data', header="true")])
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the following line:

```
tcs2 = [(state, cases, deaths) for state, cases, deaths in zip(tcs.index, tcs['cases'],tcs['deaths'])]
```

this generated the following output:

[('New York', 1203003648, 31391997), ('California', 2188008059, 30864267), ('Texas', 1745177048, 28252336),....]

so I sent to my html file using:

```
@app.route('/')
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html", table=tcs, cmap=html_map, tcs2=tcs2)
```

So I could just iterate to have my table in my html file using the code that I already had which was:

```
             {% for p in tcs2 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ p[0]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ p[1]}}</td>
                    <td>{{ p[2]}}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```